# Firefox / IE formatting dates as 1970

Tags: highcharts

I have a dataset (csv) that renders into a line graph, there is also a tool tip that displays amongst other data, the date from the dataset. In chrome it works ok, but in IE (latest) and firefox 58, it is rendering the date as '01 Jan 1970'. I assume that if the date displays ok in Chrome, other browsers would follow suit. 
This is my tooltip line:

```
<div class="tooltip-date">' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y', this.x) + '</div>
```

Has anyone any idea as to how to fix this?

The date in the csv is like so: 25-Jan-2016

I have the latest versions of highchart js and highcharts data module.

Comment: What is the value for the `this.x`?

Comment: I can suggest you add this module: <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
Also, you can find a lot of topics like this one: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9565
You can read docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module
Or you can provide an online example of your chart (jsFiddle would be the best) - then I will be able to investigate it and find a solution for you.

Comment: In Chrome (where it works ok) this.x on the first point of the graph is '1453680000000', whereas in FF, its 0 (zero). And as i move along the graph, FF just increments by 1. (i am new to HC and i have inherited a site that uses it and has this bug, so am learning as i go along, and my understanding is that this.x is the number of ms since the 1 jan 1970.)

Answer (score 1):

The value provided to [`Highcharts.dateFormat`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.dateFormat) must be a `timestamp` as a `number`. From what I understand from your explanation the provided value is a `25-Jan-2016`. You have to first parse the date either with [Highcharts](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parseDate) or before to be able to use the `dateFormat` function.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Highcharts can handle a lot of formats. More info I will add in a comment under the question.